# Swift Health Kit Query

Tags: swiftui, healthkit

i have the function `calculateBloosPresureData` in my file `HealthStore`.  I am getting the error.

```
Cannot convert value of type '[HKSample]?' to expected argument type 'HKQuantitySample?'
```

on the line  `completion(statisticsCollection)`. I want to use the data in the content view but can't get this to work.

```
 func calculateBloosPresureData(completion: @escaping (HKQuantitySample?) -> Void) {
    let presureType = HKQuantityType.correlationType(forIdentifier: .bloodPressure)!
    let startDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -7, to: Date())
    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: Date(), options:    .strictStartDate)
    
    query =  HKSampleQuery(sampleType: presureType,
                                predicate: predicate,
                                limit: HKObjectQueryNoLimit,
                                sortDescriptors: nil) { (query, statisticsCollection, error) in
                                    completion(statisticsCollection)
                                    print(statisticsCollection!)
                                }
                                
    if let healthstore = healthStore, let query = self.query {
        healthstore.execute(query)
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your completion signature does not meat `HQSampleQuery` completion results, so just change it

```
func calculateBloosPresureData(completion: @escaping ([HKSample]?) -> Void) {
   ...
```

or transform results as needed before call to external `completion(...)`